# How to move multiple upload file in different folder

Tags: php, file, upload, move

$uploaded = false;
for($i=0;$i
}

$uploaded_cc = false;
for($i=0;$i
}

Please help me..   Above program works well and store multiple files in my folder but i want store different folder. Above program works first FOR LOOP only and Second FOR LOOP con not work. what problem in my second FOR LOOP , Please reply me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple file upload in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

For loops typically have a condition in them.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: Thans for reply. I got a answer in my program. just copy the first for loop folder path in second for loop folder path,its work well $uploaded = false;                                $uploaded=$folderpath1;//first for loop         $uploaded=$folderpath; // second for loop (not include in second time:$uploaded = false; )