# How to upload/store multiple images in mysql database in php

Tags: php, html

Here I'm making a form in which user can upload multiple images

HTML Code below

`<input type='file' name='attachPhoto1' multiple />`

PHP Code below

```
        $tmp_file = $_FILES['attachPhoto1']['tmp_name'];
        $target_file = basename($_FILES['attachPhoto1']['name']);
        $upload_dir = "userUploads";
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_file,$upload_dir."/".$target_file);
```

But when I upload more than one image, then only one image get uploaded into `userUploads` folder. So please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php upload multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766035/php-upload-multiple-files)

Comment: Why is this tagged with MySQL, but does not contain any related code?

Answer (score 0):

Your input should be like this, when you upload and posting mutiple image files

`<input type='file' name='attachPhoto1[]' multiple />`

and your form should be like this

`<form action="" method="post" name="" id="" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

and following is very much working code i used, you can adjust it according to your need;

```
if(!empty($_FILES['attachPhoto1']['name'])) {
        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $error_uploads = 0;
        $total_uploads = array();
        $upload_path = 'upload/';
        foreach($_FILES['attachPhoto1']['name'] as $key => $value) {
            $temp = explode(".", $_FILES['attachPhoto1']['name'][$key]);
            $extension = end($temp);
            if ($_FILES["files"]["type"][$key] != "image/gif"
                && $_FILES["files"]["type"][$key] != "image/jpeg"
                && $_FILES["files"]["type"][$key] != "image/jpg"
                && $_FILES["files"]["type"][$key] != "image/pjpeg"
                && $_FILES["files"]["type"][$key] != "image/x-png"
                && $_FILES["files"]["type"][$key] != "image/png"
                && !in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
                $error_uploads++;
                continue;
            }
            $file_name = time().rand(1,5).rand(6,10).'_'.str_replace(' ', '_', $_FILES["attachPhoto1"]['name'][$key]);
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachPhoto1"]['tmp_name'][$key], $upload_path.$file_name)) {
                $total_uploads[] = $file_name;
            } else {
                $error_uploads++;
            }
        }
        if(sizeof($total_uploads)) {
        //Do what ever you like after file uploads, you can run query here to save it in database or set redirection after success upload
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes my form is like that as you asked but its not working

Comment: answer edited and working php code, adjust the code according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input type='file' name='attachPhoto1[]' multiple />`.
Notice the square brackets (highlighting them did not work for me).
In PHP you should iterate over the members of the $attachPhoto1[] array.

Comment: Provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this code for uploading more than one images in specified folder

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $j = 0;                       // Variable for indexing uploaded image.
   $target_path = "uploads/";    // Declaring Path for uploaded images.

   // --- Loop to get individual element from the array
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) {   
      $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");    // Extensions which are allowed.
      $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i])); // Explode file name from dot(.)
      $file_extension = end($ext); // Store extensions in the variable.
      $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];     // Set the target path with a new name of image.
      $j = $j + 1;     // Increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array.

      // --- Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
      if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000) && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
         if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {
      // If file moved to uploads folder.
            echo $j. ').<span id="noerror">Image uploaded successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
         } else {       //  If File Was Not Moved.
            echo $j. ').<span id="error">please try again!.</span><br/><br/>';
         }
      } else {          //   If File Size And File Type Was Incorrect.
         echo $j. ').<span id="error">***Invalid file Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
      }
   }
}
?>
```