# how to simple multiple file upload using name="image[ ]"

Tags: php, file-upload

Im new to `php` and would like to ask about uploading multiple files using `name="image[]"`. Here's my code :

---

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image[]" multiple="multiple"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

    $table_name ="posts";

    $_POST['submit'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $cat_id = $_POST['cat_id'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date']));
    $description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
    $status = $_POST['status'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name (title,cat_id,date,description,status) VALUES ('$title','$cat_id','$date','$description','$status')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);                
    $sqlImage = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM $table_name ORDER BY id DESC "));
    $parentId = $sqlImage['id'];
    foreach ($_POST['image'] as $images) {
        $resImage = mysql_query("INSERT INTO media (parent_id,image) VALUES ('$parentId','$images') ");
    }
    $_SESSION['add_content'] = true;    

   echo ' <script>location.href="'.$base_url.''.$table_name.'"</script>';


?>
```

How can I input my image?

Comment: What are you wanting to do with the image?

Comment: `$_POST['submit'];` by itself?  Why do you have that?  And you can do what you want, just do `foreach($_FILES as $file)` and then use `$file` as you normally would use `$_FILES['image']` [This](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php#106608) might help.

Comment: The variable `image` is not of type `$_POST` but `$_FILES`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple file upload in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `$_POST['submit']` currently doesn't do anything. Secondly uploading files requires you to use `$_FILES` instead of `$_POST`.

This should work to get all of the files uploaded

```
foreach($_FILES['image'] as $file)
{
    //do something with the data
}
```

[**PHP manual : `$_FILES`**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) 
Hope this helps!