# Error handle not working - file upload check

Tags: php, file-upload, if-statement, ifnull

I have a multiple image upload form on a page (up to 3) - but a user may choose to not upload 1 or more images at all. The script processing the the uploads when 1 or more are left blank gives me this error:

**"Warning: copy() [function.copy]: Filename cannot be empty in"....**

I have tried to use the code below to ignore the copy request if/when the field is empty but perform the copy if file upload exists but it is not working. Can someone tell me why this doesn't work or more appropriately how i need to code it differently?

**FORM**

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="processor.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div>
First Profile Image  <input name="ufile[]" type="file" /><br />
Second Profile Image <input name="ufile[]" type="file" /><br />
Third Profile Image  <input name="ufile[]" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

</div>
```

**PHP in processor.php file**

```
$pfi1= "upload/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][0];
$pfi2= "upload/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][1];
$pfi3= "upload/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][2];
if ($_FILES['ufile']['name'][0] !=="" || $_FILES['ufile']['name'][0] !==NULL) {copy($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][0], $pfi1);}
if ($_FILES['ufile']['name'][1] !=="" || $_FILES['ufile']['name'][1] !==NULL) {copy($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][1], $pfi2);}
if ($_FILES['ufile']['name'][2] !=="" || $_FILES['ufile']['name'][2] !==NULL) {copy($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][2], $fi3);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As used in a comment on this link here: [Multiple file upload in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php) Thanks to: Andy Braham for his input on that thread.

HTML

```
<input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

PHP

```
//Loop through each file
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
  //Get the temp file path
  $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

  //Make sure we have a filepath
  if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
    //Setup our new file path
    $newFilePath = "./uploadFiles/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

    //Upload the file into the temp dir
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

      //Handle other code here

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add file system level checks before using file manipulation functions such as copy.

Use `is_file()` or `file_exists()` first to check if it is ok to run `copy()` function on it

```
    if ($_FILES['ufile']['name'][0] !=="" 
       && $_FILES['ufile']['name'][0] !==NULL
       && file_exists("full/path/to/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][0])
   )
   {
     copy...
   }
```

Comment: you mean like this?  $flag1 = file_exists($_FILES['ufile']['name'][0]);
if ($flag1="1"); {copy($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'][0], $pfi1);

Comment: @Raidenance - I had a strange result, this was working briefly then something stopped working, I checked and rechecked character by character but couldn't find what broke it. Anyways I was not able to get it working again and found a different route that works here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php)