# Multiple File Upload using array

Tags: javascript, php

I have a website where people can upload an image file. Now i would like to allow users to upload multiple image files. I find it a bit confusing to make my functions accept arrays. Here is what I have :

The UI part of it:

```
<input type="file" id="imagefile" name="imagefile[]" multiple>
```

The handler function and used for logging to a txt file:

```
if(getPostPutField('imagefilename',$imagefilename))
$count=1;
foreach ($_FILES['imagefilename']['tmp_name'] as $file)
{
$imagefilename = urldecode($imagefilename);
$uploaded = handleUploadedImageFile($KBID, $_FILES['imagefile'], $imagefilename);
if ($uploaded)
{
$changesForEveryone[] .= "Image File Uploaded: " . $imagefilename."<br>";
$extraMsg .= "<br>Image File Uploaded: " . $imagefilename."<br>";
}
$count++;
}
```

The part where the file is really uploaded:

```
function handleUploadedImageFile($KBID,$file,$imagefilename=null)
{
$result = '';      
if(empty($imagefilename))
$imagefilename = $file['name'];
if($file['size'] > 0)
{
$dir = PROBLEMIMAGES."/".sprintf("%05d",$KBID)."/";
$result = getUploadedFile($file['tmp_name'],$dir,$imagefilename);
}
else
{
$result = false;
}
return $result;
}
```

How do i do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to upload all the files in a single request you can look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php)
but in order to create a better user experience it will be better to upload the files one by one using ajax take a look at the ["jQuery File Upload Demo"](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) (you can find there also the server side code in php)