# PHP MySQL multiple mp3 upload in database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm programming a script that uploads mp3 to a folder in my server and adds the title, url and artist tot the 'audio' table.

but it dont work

PHP MySQL multiple mp3 upload in database

```
<?
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die("Error Connect to Database");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("mydatabase");

for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["filUpload"]["name"]);$i++)
$target_dir = "/mounted-storage/home150/sub007/sc80538-VHHY/website.com/audio/files/";
$trackName = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
$titel      = htmlspecialchars($_POST['titel']);
$artist     = $_POST['artiest'];
{
    if($_FILES["filUpload"]["name"][$i] != "")
    {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i],"myfile/".$_FILES["filUpload"]["name"][$i]))
        {
            //*** Insert Record ***//
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `audio` (titel, url, categorie) values ('".$titel."', 'http://website.com/audio/files/".$trackName."','".$artist."')");
        }
    }
}

echo "Copy/Upload Complete<br>"; ?>
```

and the HTML form :

```html
 <form name="form1" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Track1 : <input name="titel" type="text" id="Titel" size="63" /><p>
 <input type="file" name="filUpload[]"><br>
    <br><br>
    Track2 : <input name="titel" type="text" id="Titel" size="63" /><p>
 <input type="file" name="filUpload[]"><br>
    <br><br>
    Track3 : <input name="titel" type="text" id="Titel" size="63" /><p>
 <input type="file" name="filUpload[]"><br>
    <br><br>
    Track4 : <input name="titel" type="text" id="Titel" size="63" /><p>
 <input type="file" name="filUpload[]"><br>
    <br><br>
    Track5 : <input name="titel" type="text" id="Titel" size="63" /><p>
 <input type="file" name="filUpload[]"><br>
    <br><br>
    Track6 : <input name="titel" type="text" id="Titel" size="63" /><p>
 <input type="file" name="filUpload[]"><br>
    <br><br>
    <select name="artiest">
              <?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artiesten ORDER BY naam ASC");
while ($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
 echo "<option value=\"". $array['naam'] ."\">". $array['naam']. "</option>";
}
?>
            </select>
    
 <input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: And do you expect us to guess even the error message?

Comment: Look at this carefully `$trackName = $_FILES['foto']['name'];` and `$_POST['artiest']` amongst a few others. You need to learn how to debug code.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373937/muliple-upload-php-script-and-store-in-mysql-database

Comment: *"but it dont work"* - Isn't much to go on. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. That is how you will now learn how to debug code, and is part of the learning (and coding) process.

Answer (score 0):

this is just a sample code you have to fit in your website and add mysql connection ware i leave comment or just include external file

php code

```
if (isset($_POST["upload"])){


    $userdir = "mp3/songs/";
    for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['mp3']['name']); $i++) {

    $target_file = $userdir . basename($_FILES["mp3"]["name"][$i]);
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);




            if (!file_exists($userdir)){
             mkdir($userdir, 0777, true);
            }
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["mp3"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file)) {

            // your mysql connect code or you have to be included external file with $connect variable or just rename it 
            $song = $_FILES["mp3"]["name"][0];
             $sql = sprintf(
                            "INSERT INTO music (mp3) VALUES ('%s')",
                            mysqli_escape_string($connect, $song)
                            );

                            $res = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

            echo "The file  has been uploaded.\n";
        } else {

            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.\n";
        }

  }
}
```

html code :

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="mp3[]" multiple="true" >
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload">
</form>
```

Comment: hey thank you my friend for your answer but i need to add also the titlename of each track in the database

Comment: the first i think you should name each input field like title1 title2 and ect just to identifie witch is witch and later just input them the same way i show u with an mp3 example `$sql = sprintf(
                            "INSERT INTO music (title,mp3) VALUES ('%s', '%s')",
                            mysqli_escape_string($connect, $title),mysqli_escape_string($connect, $song)
                            );` title probably will be eaqual to $_POST["title1"]; do this will all of your fields or use `for or while to do this `