# PHP Multiple File Upload infineite

Tags: php, file-upload

I have an html file for user to select two files and a button for uploading

```
<form name="frm" id ="frm" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">


Upload FILE1 : <input type="file" name="f1" id="alett" id="alett" accept="application/pdf">

Upload FILE2 : <input type="file" name="f2" id="photo" accept="application/pdf">

<button name="btnsave" type="submit">Save</Button>
```

and my php code is

```
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['btnsave'])){
        $a = $_FILES["f1"];
        print "<pre>";
        print_r($a);
        print "</pre>";

        $a = $_FILES["f2"];
        print "<pre>";
        print_r($a);
        print "</pre>";
    }
?>
```

When i upload only one file than it works fine, but when i select both file then browser only processes and nothing happen anything else.

I don't know what is problem.

i checked `max_file_uploads` and `upload_max_filesize` but it is ok.

please anyone help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple file upload in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php)

Comment: i tried only single upload like 
'FILE 1 : <input type="file" name="f[]">
    
FILE 2 : <input type="file" name="f[]">'
`$a = $_FILES["f"]` but it is not working

Comment: Just add multiple tag in input like <input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />

Comment: this is also not working :(

Comment: go through the link provided, and have a check on other things too

Comment: when i tried my first code in local machine it works fine but with remote server it is not working. what can be the reason?

Comment: try using other way if it is not working, try with this [link](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
<form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Send these files:<br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
</form>
```

post variable like below
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo.txt
            [1] => bar.txt
        )

```
[type] => Array
    (
        [0] => text/plain
        [1] => text/plain
    )

[tmp_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => /tmp/phpYzdqkD
        [1] => /tmp/phpeEwEWG
    )

[error] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 0
    )

[size] => Array
    (
        [0] => 123
        [1] => 456
    )
```

)

for more info http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: i tried this too but still the same problem arises. @AnudeepSharma