# POST an Array using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to `UPLOAD` multiple file using `Post jQuery` method but I get an error of `undefined index` when trying to view the array result. Tried to search the answers but still unable to do it. What is the correct way to do this. Below are the example of my codes,

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" name="others[]" multiple="multiple">
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
 $("#submit").click(function(){
    var array = [$("input[name='others']").val()],
        others = {
            "upload[]": array,
        },
        id =  $("input[name='id']").val();
    $.post('updated-file-others.php',
    {
        others : others,
        id : id 
    }, function(data){
        $("#result_post").html(data); 
    });  
 });
});
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $others = array($_FILES['upload']['name']);
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($others); echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things

- `$("input[name='others']")` doesnt match `others[]` in your HTML. Why dont you use an `id` and match it?
- You might need to ensure that you have 
  `enctype="multipart/form-data"` inside your form.
- whats the output of `$("input[name='id']").val();` You have not provided any clue in your code.

Refer to `php` documentation on file upload - [Uploading multiple files](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

Refer to this stackoverflow question - [Multiple file upload in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php)

Comment: The value of id is correct. It will post the id value. If I use id for example id='others'. Do I need to put '[]' as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest formatting your desired array as a JSON string, and then using `php_decode` to convert it to an array.

```
$json = '["apple","orange","banana","strawberry"]';
$ar = json_decode($json);

echo $ar[0]; // apple
```

More info about JSON with PHP can be found here:
http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/decode.php

Answer (score 0):

The file upload via ajax using $.post doesn't work this way, to achieve this, you must configure the ajax call as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: your_url,
    data: new FormData($('#form-id').get(0)),
    processData: false, //set it to false to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data
    contentType: false //pass false to tell jQuery to not set any content type header
}).done(function (data) {
    alert('success');
})
```

This will send you the entire form to the server, and there you can process the files and other fields as you want.

You can read a little more about the processData and contentType configuration in the [jQuery ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Please let us know if this work for you,

Greetings

Comment: Does it `post` or `get` the file data?

Comment: I modified the code to make it more clear, you must specify the type, to me this work with POST

Comment: thanks for the help. The error is gone but when I `print_r($others)`. The array value is empty.

Comment: Try print_r($_POST) to see if the info is content in the request

Comment: If I `print_r($_POST)` it will display the id. The id is posted but the file still empty.