# How to use foreach for multiple image upload using php and mysql

Tags: php

Here is my Form:

```
 <form action="" method="post"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input  type="file" name="file[]" id="file" /> 
     <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Here is my php:

```
 <?php
     $file=$_FILES['file']['name'];
     $dest="uploads/$file";
     $src=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
     move_uploaded_file($src,$dest);
 ?>
```

How to use `foreach` after hitting the submit button? kindly guide me please.

```
MY FOR EACH GIVES ONLY ONE VALUE. I UPLOADED MORE THAN TWO IMAGE.iT SHOWS LAST ONE
foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $k=>$v)
{

echo "File : ", $_FILES['file']['name'][$k] ," is valid, and was                      successfully uploaded.\n";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple file upload in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php)

Comment: not a problem kindly solve the issue. no for each was there. and it is not working, i tried, if u want , u please try.

Comment: U can use foreach  instead of for in php section of first answer that has 113 score.

Comment: ok. I have used foreach only, my question is I am uploading more than two  image at a time.In foreach how do i want to see those values, foreach($f as $k=>$v) { echo $v } like this how do I see my uploaded image, uploaded image is more than two.please test and give answer.

Comment: Hi tested it gives only lAST VALUE, CHECK MY QUESTION

Comment: if possible can you see why my foreach is not showing all the image which i uploaded. rest of the things we discuss later. I want to understand step by step, because I am working as a tutor.

Comment: I added another link for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

```
foreach ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] as $key => $val ) {
    $filename = $_FILES['image']['name'][$key];
    $filesize = $_FILES['image']['size'][$key];
    $filetempname = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key];

    $fileext = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $fileext = strtolower($fileext);

    // here your insert query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi your question seems incomplete but i'll try to answer

an a example to process

`foreach($file as $oneFile){
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO {{your table name}} VALUES ("+oneFile+")")
}`

but it work only if you have initialise a connexion to mysql

Comment: where to put print_r($onefile). I will upload three image at a time and i want to see ? what print_R says

Comment: put it here 

`foreach($file as $oneFile){
   echo($oneFile);
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO {{your table name}} VALUES ("+oneFile+")")
}`

and use echo instead print_r cause print_R is for array and $oneFile is not an array

Comment: boss print_r($oneFile) gives only lastupload name., I uploaded two image at a time. let us see first print_r values

Comment: where have you put your print_r ? put in into the foreach

Comment: foreach($file as $oneFile){
      print_r($oneFile);
}

Comment: give the output please

Comment: network.png, i uploaded two image print_r($oneFile) shows only last one. u try at your end, then we move to insert query

Comment: Have  you tested? what print_r says if we upload more than two image

Comment: print_r just output the content of your var so the problem come from $file it seems $file content only the last of your image

Comment: no, i am uploading more than one image at a time ,then how to see if i upload more images. i want to send  more image to folder and db

Comment: i understand .. just put a var_dump($file) if on your output you have only one image the problem come from your way to get the value !

Comment: hi it shows only  last image both var_dump and print_R,  var_dump result is=string(12) "wireless.png"

Comment: SEE MY QUESTION I ADDED FOREACH ALSO