# Upload multiple image in database PHP

Tags: php

I found the code below online to import multiple images in the database, however the following condition seems to always return false because the code inside is never executed: `(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath))`. Is it because of the `path`? I didn't change anything and I assumed that `uploaded` is created automatically.

```
<?php include 'connection.php';?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    if(count($_FILES['upload']['name']) > 0){
        echo "OhhYESHOOO";
        //Loop through each file
        for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {
          //Get the temp file path
            $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
            echo "HERE";

            //Make sure we have a filepath
            if($tmpFilePath != ""){
            echo "Entered";
                //save the filename
                $shortname = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
                //echo "*$shortname";
                //save the url and the file
                $filePath = "uploaded/" . date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

                //Upload the file into the temp dir
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath)) {
                    echo "Entered Again";
                    $files[] = $shortname;
                    //insert into db 
                    //use $shortname for the filename
                    //use $filePath for the relative url to the file

                }
              }
        }
    }

    //show success message
    echo "<h1>Uploaded:</h1>";    
    if(is_array($files)){
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($files as $file){
            echo "<li>$file</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and you mention database but no code for the question

Comment: Google it before.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php

Comment: @Fred-ii- True but I assumed that `$filePath` will be what I'll insert as image. right?

Comment: I think my issue is where I define the path

Comment: there is no such resource as  $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i]

Comment: try a foreach loop like shown here: http://techstream.org/Web-Development/PHP/Multiple-File-Upload-with-PHP-and-MySQL

Comment: what was posted up there has a few solutions, and the manual also has an example http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php - If your form's input doesn't allow for multiples, or isn't an array, then that too could contribute to the problem and we don't know what the form looks like. Make sure the folder is writeable also.