# PHP upload multiple files to FTP

Tags: php, file, upload, ftp

I'm trying to upload files to FTP through PHP, and it works... sort of. Please have a look at my code;

```
        $filename = $_FILES['files']['name'];
            $host = "ftp.mydomain.com";
            $username = "myusername";
            $password = "mypassword";
            $local_file = 'upload/'.$filename;
            $remote_file = $filename;

            $con = ftp_connect($host, 21) or die("Couldnt connect");
            $log = ftp_login($con, $username, $password) or die("Wrong username or password.");

            ftp_pasv($con, true);

            $upload = ftp_put($con, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY);
            if($upload) echo 'Error.';
            ftp_close($con);

            echo 'Success';
            exit;
```

This script actually work, but just with ONE file. If I'm uploading multiple files through my form, it will just upload one file. I want all of the files from my form to be uploaded. How can I do that?

Comment: Put a loop in the PHP code.

Comment: How? I'm really new into PHP. @Barmar

Comment: With a `foreach()` statement to loop over the elements of an array.

Comment: I have this code to echo all files uploaded, but I have no idea how I can implement this into the FTP script to get all of them uploaded @Barmar ;

    for($i = 0; $i < count($data['data']['metas']); $i++)
  {
      echo "<li>".$data['data']['metas'][$i]["name"]."</li>";
  }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into loops. One solution could be to loop through all files you get from your form with a [foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), e.g.:

```
foreach($_FILES['files'] as $file){
    // your upload logic here
}
```

You will also have to adjust the logic in your html upload form. You have to account for multiple `$_FILES['files']`, e.g. in the format of `$_FILES['files'][0]`, `$_FILES['files'][1]`,...,`$_FILES['files'][n]`

I hope this will give you some direction :-)

Comment: I'll give this a shot! Thanks. I'm new in PHP, but I'm learning the ropes!

Comment: I honestly believe you have a good answer for me here @jrn . However, I'm new to this and I'm struggling to implement this and to get it working. By adjusting the html upload form, you mean for example <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" multiple /> ?

Comment: Try something like this `<input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />`. Make sure you have the `[]` after the input name.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a go. And then wrap my code that I posted here with this? foreach($_FILES['files'] as $file){
    // my upload script here
}

Comment: Yes, but adjust it accordingly: `$_FILES['upload']`

Comment: You also might want to check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php) :-)

Comment: This was great help, @jrn. After a whole day trying to figure this out, my brain was toasted. After a good nights sleep and with your tips, I got this all sorted out. Thanks for your time!