# How can I upload two different files in PHP with move_uploaded_file()

Tags: php, web

I've done some googling but I just can't find the right answer, maybe I am searching wrong but can you please help me move two uploaded files in a form at the same time.

At the moment the first upload works fine but the second one doesn't semm to work at all.

Oh, and by the way they are two different files. One is an image and the other one is a song (a .mp3 file).

Hope it's not a duplicate .

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Maybe this question can help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php