# Multiple File uploading via php

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="" name="fname" />
    <input type="file"  name="filepath" id="filepath"/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

 -----------------php-----------------------------------   
    $newname=$_POST['fname'];
    $target_dir = 'uploads/reports/';
    $filename=$_FILES["filepath"]['name'];
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $_FILES["filepath"]['name']=$newname.".".$ext;

    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["filepath"]['name']);
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $_FILES["tmp_name"]=$newname;
    echo $target_file;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filepath"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);

    }
```

i need  to upload multiple files (excel,word documents,images) from single input(i mean , we could select multiple files when we browse) to database , this code is work only for one file.and rename that file as $newnam(1),$newname(2).... like that

Comment: It's not recommended uploading files to the database, you probably want to upload them to the server and just store the image path into the database.

Comment: This question is better answered here.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple file upload in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php)

Comment: This question is better answered here: [Multiple file upload in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php)

Comment: @BoianIvanov but im designing a interface for input project details and project files report files to the server , and im trying to display and download that files wen we needed,

Comment: @SLcLaY you can still achieve this by saving the files in the server, and storing the file path in the database. When you need to present the file to the user, you give him the directory and he can access the needed file.

Comment: @BoianIvanov now see the code , from this, only i can save one file and rename it, i want store multiple files store like that  and renamed it

Comment: @jeger now i uploaded again whaat i have done please refer the code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to provide the input name as an array and provide the `multiple` attribute like:

```
<input type="file"  name="filepath[]" id="filepath" multiple />
```

and you can get its content using:

```
$_FILES['filepath']  // It returns an array
```