# Add multiple images to one product on the product details page using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, upload

I am working on a basic e-commerce website using PHP/MYSQL. I just need to know how I can upload multiple images for a product and then display them on the product details page in this format [Example of what I'm trying to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNMla.jpg)

[image]

I've been trying to figure out how I can display these images (multiple images for 1 product). I really don't understand how it should work! so any advice on simple terms would be appreciated.

Currently, I can only upload 1 image per product.
Here is what I have so far (1 Image per product),

#### For the Product Class Page

```
<?php
class Product{

private $db;
private $fm;   

public function __construct(){
    $this->db = new Database();
    $this->fm = new Format();

}

public function productInsert($data, $file){
    $productName = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['productName']);
    $catId = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['catId']);
    $body = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['body']);
    $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['price']);
    $type = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['type']);
    $town = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['town']);
    $quantity = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['quantity']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['email']);
    $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['phone']);
    $contactName = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['contactName']);


    $permited  = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');
    $file_name = $file['image']['name'];
    $file_size = $file['image']['size'];
    $file_temp = $file['image']['tmp_name'];

    $div = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($div));
    $unique_image = substr(md5(time()), 0, 10).'.'.$file_ext;
    $uploaded_image = "../uploads/".$unique_image;

    if($productName == "" || $catId == "" || $price == "" || $file_name == "" || $town == ""  || $quantity == "" || $email == "" || $phone == "" || $contactName == ""){
        $msg = "<span class='error'>Fields must not be empty!</span>";
        return $msg;

    } elseif ($file_size >1048567) {
         echo "<span class='error'>Image Size should be less then 1MB!
     </span>";

    } elseif (in_array($file_ext, $permited) === false) {
        echo "<span class='error'>You can upload only:-".implode(', ', $permited)."</span>";

    } else{
        move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $uploaded_image);
        $query = "INSERT INTO products(productName, catId, body, price, image, type, town, quantity, email, phone, contactName) VALUES('$productName','$catId','$body','$price','$uploaded_image', '$type','$town','$quantity','$email','$phone','$contactName')";
        $inserted_row = $this->db->insert($query);

            if($inserted_row){
                    $msg = "<span class='success'> Your Offer is Added Successfully. </span>";
                    return $msg;
                } else{
                    $msg = "<span class='error'> Sorry! Your offer is not added! Try again later. </span>";
                    return $msg;
                }
    }
}
```

#### For the Add Product Page

```
             <?php 
                $product = new Product();
                if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $insertProduct = $product->productInsert($_POST, $_FILES);

                      }
                  ?>
        <form action="" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

          <!-- Add Product start -->
          <div class="location">
             <!-- Product select start -->
              <div class="styled-select-car">
                 <select name="catId" id="my_selection" style ="font-size:18px;">
                 <option value="">Select the Offer Category* (Required)</option>
                  <?php
                        $cat = new Category();  
                        $getCat = $cat->getAllCat();
                        if($getCat){
                            while($result = $getCat->fetch_assoc()){
                   ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $result['catId'];?>"><?php echo $result['catName'];?></option>

                  <?php } } ?>
                  <br>
                  </select>
                </div>
            <!-- Product select end -->
               <div class="input-group pick-up">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Offer*</span>
                  <input type="text" name="productName" id="pick-up-location" class="form-control " placeholder="Enter Your Product or Service Title (Required)"> 
               </div>
                         <br>
                       <div class="input-group pick-up">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Price* </span>
                  <input type="text" name="price" id="pick-up-location" class="form-control " placeholder="Enter Your Product or Service Price (Required)">
               </div>
                       <br>

                       <div class="input-group pick-up">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Location* </span>
                  <input type="text" name="town" id="pick-up-location" class="form-control " <?php if(Session::get("customerTown")) {?>value="<?php echo Session::get("customerTown");?>" <?php } else { ?> placeholder="Enter Your Location Description (Required)" <?php } ?>>
               </div>
                         <br>
                      <div class="input-group pick-up">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Quantity* </span>
                  <input type="text" name="quantity" id="pick-up-location" class="form-control " placeholder="Enter Your Product's or Service Quantity* (Required)">
              </div>
                      <br>
                      <div class="input-group pick-up">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Email*</span>
                  <input type="text" name="email" id="pick-up-location" class="form-control " <?php if(Session::get("customerEmail")) {?>value="<?php echo Session::get("customerEmail");?>" <?php } else { ?> placeholder="Enter Your Email Address (Required)" <?php } ?>>
              </div>
                      <br>

                      <div class="input-group pick-up">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Phone Number* </span>
                  <input type="text" name="phone" id="pick-up-location" class="form-control " <?php if(Session::get("customerPhone")) {?>value="<?php echo Session::get("customerPhone");?>" <?php } else { ?> placeholder="Enter Your Phone Number (Required)" <?php } ?>>
              </div>
                      <br>
             <div class="input-group pick-up">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Contact Name* </span>
                  <input type="text" name="contactName" id="pick-up-location" class="form-control " <?php if(Session::get("customerName")) {?>value="<?php echo Session::get("customerName");?>" <?php } else { ?> placeholder="Enter Your Contact Name (Required)" <?php } ?> >
             </div>
             <br>
                     <div class="input-group pick-up">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span> Product Image* </span>
                  <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" placeholder="">
             </div>
                     <br>

                <p><b>Give a detailed description of your product or service(Required):</b></p>  
               <textarea name="body" ></textarea>
        </div>
            <input style ="font-size:18px;" type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Add Offer" >
      </form>
```

#### For the Product Details Page

```
    <?php
     if(!isset($_GET['productid']) || $_GET['productid'] == NULL){
        echo "<script>window.location = '404.php'; </script>";
    } else {
            $id = preg_replace('/[^-a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '', $_GET['productid']);
    }
    ?>
<div class="main">
<div class="content">
    <div class="section group">
    <div class="cont-desc span_1_of_2"> 
    <?php 
        $getProduct = $product->getSingleProduct($id);
        if($getProduct){
            while($result = $getProduct->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>          
                <div class="grid images_3_of_2">
                    <img src="<?php echo $result['image']; ?>" alt="" />
                </div>
            <div class="desc span_3_of_2">


            <div class="product-information"><!--/product-information-->

                            <h2><?php echo $result['productName']; ?></h2>
                            <p>Contact Name: <?php if($result['contactName'] == NULL){ ?> 
                                    Guest
                            <?php } else { echo $result['contactName'];}
                                ?>  </p>

                            <img src="images/rating.png" alt="" /></br>
                            <span>
                                <span>FCFA <?php echo number_format($result['price']); ?></span>
                                <label>Quantity:</label>
                                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $result['quantity']; ?>" />

                            </span>
                            <p><b>Availability:</b> In Stock</p>
                            <p><b>Category:</b> <?php echo $result['catName']; ?></p>
                            <p><b>Town:</b> <?php echo $result['town']; ?></p>
                            <?php
                            $contact = $result['phone'];
                            $contact = substr_replace($contact,"*******",2,6);
                            ?>
                            <p><b>Telephone:</b> <?php echo $contact; ?></p>
                            <p><b>Email:</b> <?php echo mask_email($result['email']); ?></p>
                            <a href=""><img src="images/share.png" class="share img-responsive"  alt="" /></a>
                            <div class="add-cart">
                                <form action="" method="post">
                                    <input type="submit" class="buysubmit" name="submit" value="View Contact Details"/>
                                </form>             
                            </div>
                            <span style="color: red; font-size: 18px;">
                                <?php 
                                    if(isset($addCart)){
                                        echo $addCart;
                                    }

                                ?>

                            </span>
                        </div><!--/product-information-->

        </div>

        <div class="product-desc">
        <h2>Offer Details</h2>
        <pre> <?php echo $result['body']; ?> </pre>
    </div>

    <?php } } ?>
```

Can anyone help me on how I can modify this code to be able to upload multiple images per product and to be able to retrieve these image on the product details page?

Comment: Your <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" placeholder=""> add attribute multiple. Change the file handling of the uploaded files to loop through the result. On the web page implement a carousel.

Comment: Yeah, I will implement a carousel but what I'm trying to say is how can I retrieve these images from the database with the same product id?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple file upload in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

To upload multiple images you can use

```
<input type="file" name="image[]" multiple>
```

and to retrieve images just loop through with the `mysql_fetch_array()` method

```
$sql="SELECT * 
FROM tbl_image
WHERE productId= 1 ";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {
      $image=$row ['photo'];
      echo '<img src="path/'.$image.'" width="360" height="150">';

  }
```