# PHP $_FILES not using all file inputs

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, file

I'm having to patch a PHP Mail parser. Thing is, the `$_FILES` variable only manages the first file input. The way things are set, the input looks like this:
`<input type="file" name="form.steps.0.field.4" />`.
Thing is, the next input is input is the same where the name is incremented, like so: `<input type="file" name="form.steps.0.field.5" />`.

When looping the `$_FILES`, this is the current logic:

```
foreach($_FILES as $input) {
    ...
}
```

In this case, the `$_FILES` only has the file of `<input type="file" name="form.steps.0.field.4" />`, whereas the second file input is treated as text and it's value is `C:\\fakepath\\`*{filename}*.

Without using a single input name like `<input type="file" name="files[]" />`, how can I achieve this?

#### Edit:

`var_dump` of `$_FILES` produces the following:

```
array(1) {
    ["files"]=>
        array(5) {
            ["name"]=>
                array(1) {
                    [0]=>
                    string(22) "Checklist-template.pdf"
                }
            ["type"]=>
                array(1) {
                    [0]=>
                    string(15) "application/pdf"
                }
            ["tmp_name"]=>
                array(1) {
                    [0]=>
                    string(14) "/tmp/phpZxkSFz"
                }
            ["error"]=>
                array(1) {
                    [0]=>
                    int(0)
                }
            ["size"]=>
                array(1) {
                    [0]=>
                    int(115033)
            }
        }
    }
```

---

#### Edit #2

Adding action (to be used on front and back end) :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_sp_form_submit', 'spForm_submit', 10, 1);
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sp_form_submit', 'spForm_submit', 10, 1);
```

The PHP executing the data :

```
function spForm_submit(){
    if(!(is_array($_POST) && defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX)){
        return;
    }
    var_dump( $_FILES );
    die();
}
```

The JS with the AJAX Call :

```
$('.sp-form .btn-submit').unbind('click').bind('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $('input[type="hidden"]', form).each(function(){
        data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    });

    var fd = new FormData(),
        file_inputs = $('input[type="file"]', form);

    $.each($(file_inputs), function(i, obj) {
        $.each(obj.files,function(j,file){
            fd.append('files[' + j + ']', file);
        });
    });

    function appendFormdata(FormData, data, name, cback){
        name = name || '';
        if (typeof data === 'object'){
            $.each(data, function(index, value){
                if (name === ''){
                    appendFormdata(FormData, value, index, cback);
                } else {
                    appendFormdata(FormData, value, name + '['+index+']', cback);
                }
            });
        } else {
            FormData.append(name, data);
        }
    }

    appendFormdata(fd, {form: data}, null);
    fd.append( 'action', 'sp_form_submit' );

    $.ajax({
        url         : window.forms_cback, // AJAX URL
        type        : "POST",

        data        : fd,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        dataType    : "json",
        success     : function(response) {
            // removed for the purpose of the post
        }
    });
});
```

And the output of the `$_FILES` array :

```
array(1) {
    ["files"]=>
        array(5) {
            ["name"]=>
                array(1) {
                    [0]=>
                    string(22) "Checklist-template.pdf"
                }
            ["type"]=>
                array(1) {
                    [0]=>
                    string(15) "application/pdf"
                }
            ["tmp_name"]=>
                array(1) {
                    [0]=>
                    string(14) "/tmp/phpZxkSFz"
                }
            ["error"]=>
                array(1) {
                    [0]=>
                    int(0)
                }
            ["size"]=>
                array(1) {
                    [0]=>
                    int(115033)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It should have all the file inputs. Can you post `var_dump($_FILES)`

Comment: @Barmar I've added the var_dump to the question

Comment: That's the dump for `<input type="file" name="files[]">` not `<input type="file" name="form.steps.0.field.4">`

Comment: @Barmar my code is actually `var_dump($_FILES); die(); `

Comment: This `$_FILES` is from the form that has `name="files[]"`, not `name="form.steps.0.field.4"`

Comment: @Barmar I'm getting only a single file in my array

Comment: Are all the file inputs in the same `<form>`?

Comment: Where is `C:\\fakepath\\` coming from?

Comment: @Barmar the `C:\\fakepath` is coming from when I `var_dump` my `$_POST` data. I'm getting the file name but not the file itself anywhere

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php) the first answer you will see i am sure it will help.

Comment: Are you using AJAX to upload the file or normal form submission.

Comment: @Barmar yes, in WP

Comment: I don't know how to do it in WP, but you must be doing it differently for the second input than the first one. You need to post your code.

Comment: @Barmar I've updated the question with my current working code

Comment: You have a typo. In `fd.append('files[' + j + ']', file);` the variable should be `i`, not `j`.

Comment: @Barmar I've put your comment as an answer and marked as the proper solution.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: @davewoodhall Typo questions should just be closed, answers are not useful to save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Barmar, my issue was not in my `$_FILES` array but by a typo in my FileData manipulation.

[Quote :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52120558/php-files-not-using-all-file-inputs?noredirect=1#comment91263074_52120558)

> You have a typo. In `fd.append('files[' + j + ']', file);` the variable should be `i`, not `j`.