# How to upload multiple files using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know how to modify the following code to make it upload multiple files by selecting once. By the following code I am able to upload one file at a time. Just wish to modify it as through this code not only I am uploading the file but also showing all the files uploaded, on the same page for download and delete.

```
    <html>
    <title>Brief upload</title>

    <link href="globe.png" rel="shortcut icon">
    <?php
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
    //echo date_default_timezone_get();
    ?>


    <?php
    $conn=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=deu', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])!=""){
      $name=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
      $size=$_FILES['photo']['size'];
      $type=$_FILES['photo']['type'];
      $temp=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
      $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      $caption1=$_POST['caption'];
      $link=$_POST['link'];

      move_uploaded_file($temp,"files/".$name);

    $query=$conn->query("INSERT INTO upload (name,date) VALUES ('$name','$date')");
    if($query){
    header("location:index.php");
    }
    else{
    die(mysql_error());
    }
    }
    ?>


    <html>
    <body>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/DT_bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    </head>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" language="javascript" src="js/DT_bootstrap.js"></script>
    <?php include('dbcon.php'); ?>
    <style>
    .table tr th{

        border:#eee 1px solid;

        position:relative;
        #font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        font-size:12px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        }
        table tr td{

        border:#eee 1px solid;
        color:#000;
        position:relative;
        #font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        font-size:12px;

        text-transform:uppercase;
        }

    #wb_Form1
    {
       background-color: #00BFFF;
       border: 0px #000 solid;

    }
    #photo
    {
       border: 1px #A9A9A9 solid;
       background-color: #00BFFF;
       color: #fff;
       font-family:Arial;
       font-size: 20px;
    }
        </style>

        <div class="alert alert-info">


                                    Brief Uploading System 
                                </div>
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-bordered">

                <tr><td><form enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="" id="wb_Form1" name="form" method="post">

                        <!--<input type="file" name="photo[]" id="photo" multiple>-->
                        <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo"  required="required"></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="SUBMIT" name="submit">
                </form> <strong>SUBMIT HERE</strong></tr></td></table>
                                 <div class="col-md-18">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:0px;">
       <div class = "row">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">


                                <form method="post" action="delete.php" >
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-condensed" id="example">

                                <thead>

                                    <tr>

                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>FILE NAME</th>
                                       <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Download</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <?php 
$query=mysql_query("select * from upload ORDER BY id DESC")or die(mysql_error());
                                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                                $id=$row['id'];
                                $name=$row['name'];
                                $date=$row['date'];
                                ?>

                                <tr>

<td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['date'] ?></td>
<td>
<a href="download.php?filename=<?php echo $name;?>" title="click to download"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip" style="font-size:20px; color:blue"></span></a></td>
<td>
<a href="delete.php?del=<?php echo $row['id']?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="font-size:20px; color:red"></span></a>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
                </form>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple file upload in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can upload multiple files in this way

1. Input field must be defined as an array i.e. `images[]`
2. It should be defined as `multiple="multiple"`

   ```
   <input name="images[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />

   // Count # of uploaded files in array
   $total = count($_FILES['images']['name']);

   // Loop through each file
   for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {

     //Get the temp file path
     $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i];

     //Make sure we have a file path
     if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
     //Setup our new file path
     $newFilePath = "./uploadFiles/" . $_FILES['images']['name'][$i];

   //Upload the file into the temp dir
   if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

     //Handle other code here

    }
    }
   }
   ```

For more details [PHP Multiple Upload](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

Comment: using foreach would make more sense to loop the files

Comment: have done the following changes to my code through which I am able to select multiple files but only file name is being inserted in database table and file is not moved to the specified folder :-                                                              
  $name=$_FILES['upload']['name'];
  $temp=$_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
  $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  foreach ($_FILES['upload']['name'] as $name){
  move_uploaded_file($temp, 'files/' . $name);
  $query=$conn->query("INSERT INTO upload (name,date) VALUES ('$name','$date')");}

Comment: @BalKrishanDubey make sure $newFilePath have the correct path

Comment: Thanks Raymond and Rakesh, have fixed my code by using foreach