# Problem with uploading multiple photos into database through pivot table

Tags: php

I am working on a cms for properties/ads in oop php for learning purposes. I am trying to upload multiple photos that are connected through pivot table with specific property but I am having trouble inserting those photos. I need when I insert property with two or more photos that those photos have diiferent ids in pivot table but the same id for property. I succeeded with one photo at the time, but with multiple I get errors:

> **Warning**: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\App\Models\Ad.php on line 177  when I var dump $tmp
>   variable I get null and
>
> **Warning**: end() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\App\Models\Ad.php on line 179  when I var dump
>   $file_ext variable I get empty string

I am using three tables to do that. photos (name, extension, created_at, updated_at), property_photo (property_id, photo_id), properties (title, description, type_of_property, use_of_the_property, quadrature, location...). Here is my code:

```
Ad Model:

public function createAd($data, $pht)
{    
    if (isset($data['photoExtension'])) { 
      $this->photoExtension = preg_replace('~(?<=a)\w~', "", $data['photoExtension']);
    }

    $this->photoExtension = strtolower(strrchr( $pht, '.' ));

    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO properties (title, description, type_of_property, use_of_the_property, quadrature, location, price, sales_clerk_info, booked, type_of_market, type_of_payment, status) VALUES (:title, :description, :type_of_property, :use_of_the_property, :quadrature, :location, :price, :sales_clerk_info, :booked, :type_of_market, :type_of_payment, :status) ");
    $this->db->bind(':title', $data['title']);
    $this->db->bind(':description', $data['description']);
    $this->db->bind(':type_of_property', $data['type_of_property']);
    $this->db->bind(':use_of_the_property', $data['use_of_the_property']);
    $this->db->bind(':quadrature', $data['quadrature']);
    $this->db->bind(':location', $data['location']);
    $this->db->bind(':price', $data['price']);
    $this->db->bind(':sales_clerk_info', $data['sales_clerk_info']);
    $this->db->bind(':booked', $data['booked']);
    $this->db->bind(':type_of_market', $data['type_of_market']);
    $this->db->bind(':type_of_payment', $data['type_of_payment']);
    $this->db->bind(':status','1');
    $this->db->execute();

    $property_last_id = $this->db->lastId();

    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO photos (name, extension) VALUES (:name, :extension)');
    $this->db->bind(':name', $pht);
    $this->db->bind(':extension', $this->photoExtension, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $this->db->execute();

    $photo_last_id = $this->db->lastId();

    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO property_photo (property_id, photo_id) VALUES (:property_id, :photo_id)');
    $this->db->bind(':property_id', $property_last_id);
    $this->db->bind(':photo_id', $photo_last_id);
    $this->db->execute();
    return true;
}

public function photoValidate($file)
{
  if (!empty($file['name'])) {
    $file_name = $file['name'];
    $file_size = $file['size'];
    $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $file_type = $file['type'];
    $file_error = $file['error'];
    $random = sha1(microtime());
    $tmp = explode('.', $file_name);
    $new_photo_name = $random . '.' . $tmp[1];
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($tmp));
    //var_dump($tmp); null
    //var_dump($file_ext); empty string
    $photo_validate = '';

    $extensions = ["jpeg", "jpg", "png"];

    if (in_array($file_ext, $extensions) === false) {
      return 'extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.';
    } else {
      if ($file_size > 2097152 || $file_error === 1) {

        return 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
      } else {
        $value = true;
        return $data = [$value, $file_tmp, $new_photo_name];
      }
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Ads Controller:

```
public function createAction()
{
    $userinfo = $this->Auth->Auth(array('admin', 'moderator'));
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        $data = [
            'title' => trim($_POST['title']),
            'description' => trim($_POST['description']),
            'type_of_property' => trim($_POST['type_of_property']),
            'use_of_the_property' => trim($_POST['use_of_the_property']),
            'quadrature' => trim($_POST['quadrature']),
            'location' => trim($_POST['location']),
            'price' => trim($_POST['price']),
            'sales_clerk_info' => trim($_POST['sales_clerk_info']),
            'booked' => trim($_POST['booked']),
            'type_of_market' => trim($_POST['type_of_market']),
            'type_of_payment' => trim($_POST['type_of_payment']),
            'title_err' => '',
            'description_err' => '',
            'type_of_property_err' => '',
            'use_of_the_property_err' => '',
            'quadrature_err' => '',
            'location_err' => '',
            'price_err' => '',
            'sales_clerk_info_err' => '',
            'booked_err' => '',
            'type_of_market_err' => '',
            'type_of_payment_err' => ''
        ];

        if (empty($data['title'])) {
            $data['title_err'] = 'Please enter your title!!!';
        }
        if (empty($data['description'])) {
            $data['description_err'] = 'Please enter your description!!!';
        }
        if (empty($data['type_of_property'])) {
            $data['type_of_property_err'] = 'Please select your type!!!';
        }
        if (empty($data['use_of_the_property'])) {
            $data['use_of_the_property_err'] = 'Please enter use of the property!!!';
        }
        if (empty($data['quadrature'])) {
            $data['quadrature_err'] = 'Please enter your quadrature!!!';
        }
        if (empty($data['location'])) {
            $data['location_err'] = 'Please enter your location!!!';
        }
        if (empty($data['price'])) {
            $data['price_err'] = 'Please enter your price!!!';
        }
        if (empty($data['sales_clerk_info'])) {
            $data['sales_clerk_info_err'] = 'Please enter your info!!!';
        }
        if (empty($data['booked'])) {
            $data['booked_err'] = 'Please select!!!';
        }
        if (empty($data['type_of_market'])) {
            $data['type_of_market_err'] = 'Please select your type of market!!!';
        }
        if (empty($data['type_of_payment'])) {
            $data['type_of_payment_err'] = 'Please select your type of payment!!!';
        }   

        $photo_validate = $this->AdModel->photoValidate($_FILES['photo']);

        if (empty($data['title_err']) && empty($data['description_err']) && empty($data['type_of_property_err']) && empty($data['use_of_the_property_err']) && empty($data['quadrature_err']) && empty($data['location_err']) && empty($data['price_err']) && empty($data['sales_clerk_info_err']) && empty($data['booked_err']) && empty($data['type_of_market_err']) && empty($data['type_of_payment_err']) && $photo_validate[0] === true) {

            move_uploaded_file($photo_validate[1],"public/photos/".$photo_validate[2]);

            if ($this->AdModel->createAd($data, $photo_validate[2])) {
                redirect('ads/index');
            } else {
                if ($photo_validate === false) {
                    $photo_validate='Please select image';
                } else {
                    if ($photo_validate[0] === true) {
                        $photo_validate='';
                    }
                }
                $data=[

                    'photo_validate'=>$photo_validate
                ];

                die('Something went wrong!');
            }
        } else {
            $this->view->render('ads/create', $data, $userinfo);
        }
    } else {
        $data = [
            'photo_validate'=>'',
            'title' => '',
            'description' => '',
            'type_of_property' => '',
            'use_of_the_property' => '',
            'quadrature' => '',
            'location' => '',
            'price' => '',
            'sales_clerk_info' => '',
            'booked' => '',
            'type_of_market_id' => '',
            'type_of_payment' => '',
            'title_err' => '',
            'description_err' => '',
            'type_of_property_err' => '',
            'use_of_the_property_err' => '',
            'quadrature_err' => '',
            'location_err' => '',
            'price_err' => '',
            'sales_clerk_info_err' => '',
            'booked_err' => '',
            'type_of_market_err' => '',
            'type_of_payment_err' => ''
        ];

        $this->view->render('ads/create', $data, $userinfo);
    }
}
```

create.php

```
<form action="/ads/create" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h5>Upload property image</h6> 
            <input type="file" name="photo[]" multiple class="form-control form-control-lg"/>
        </div>
    /div>
    <div class="form-group">
             <button type="submit" name="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     </div>
  </form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at array format of $_FILES for multiple files inserting. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php) and [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php) php documentation page will be useful for you.

You expected string in photoValidate() $file['name'] but there was an array, so you got an error.

The best and the simplest way is to use something like symfony [http-foundation component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html).

Controller:

```
public function createAction()
{
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    //...
    $photo_validate = $this->AdModel->photoValidate($request->files->get('photo'));
    //...
}
```

Also, this kind of validation is pretty messy. You can also use [symfony validator component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/validator.html).