# PHP won't process multiple files (Chrome)

Tags: php, html

I basically want to upload multiple files into a php to process but php only takes one of the files I selected to upload

my html:

```html
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="userfiles[]" multiple="multiple">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

my php for now:

```php
echo '<pre>', print_r($_FILES), '</pre>';
$countfiles = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
```

and the output:

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => pigeon.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => D:\Programs\xampp\tmp\phpA3DF.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 105291
        )

)
1
```

no matter how many files I select only one gets processed.
Thanks in advance :)

IE works fine for some reason..

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple file upload in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php)

Comment: you want single input to select multiple files ?????

Comment: or like a add more input fields (single image in one input file) ????

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I had to do was to start Apache before chrome...