# end() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given when working with $_FILES

Tags: php

This is some part of my HTML code, I added `[]` because I have multiple row that requires more image to be uploaded for each row.

`<td><input type="file" class="form-control total" name="myfile[]" readonly></td>`

Problem is, when I ran the code to extract string from `myfile` using `implode()` and use
it on `end()`. It return this error message

> Warning: end() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in ... on line 39

```
    $arr_supplier = $_POST['supplier'];
    
    $f_name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $f_tmp = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']; 
    $f_size = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];
    $f_extension = implode('.',$f_name); 
    $f_extension = strtolower(end($f_extension)); // Line 39
    echo $f_newfile = uniqid().'.'.$f_extension;
    $store = "productimages/".$f_newfile;
    if($f_extension == 'jpg' || $f_extension == 'png' || $f_extension == 'gif' || $f_extension == 'jpeg'){
        if($f_size >= 1000000){
        echo 'file size too large';
                
        } else {
            if(move_uploaded_file($f_tmp, $store)){
                $product_details = $f_newfile;
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo 'file type invalid';
    }
...
```

Comment: On the previous line, you probably meant to use `explode()` rather than `implode()`.

Comment: when i use explode, it returns this `Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given`

Comment: @MuhammadNurAliif when you are uploading multiple files, the data layout is a little different. You need to do some research (or `print_r()` your variables to observe) to see what's going on and why.

Comment: Read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php

Comment: you should use explode instead of implode, implode will join the array by glue and return to string

Answer (score 0):

The error pretty much explains the problem, the [end](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) method expects an array as argument and you are passing a string that is returned from the call to [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload each and every product image separately through loop.
Your code should be something like:

```
  $product_Details = array();   
  for($i=0;$i<COUNT($_FILES['myfile']);$i++)
  {
     $f_name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i];
     $f_tmp = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$i]; 
     $f_size = $_FILES['myfile']['size'][$i];
     $f_extension = end((explode(".", $f_name)));
     echo $f_newfile = uniqid().'.'.$f_extension;
     $store = "productimages/".$f_newfile;
     if($f_extension == 'jpg' || $f_extension == 'png' || $f_extension == 'gif' || 
     $f_extension == 'jpeg')
     {
        if($f_size >= 1000000){
          echo 'file size too large';                
        } else {
          if(move_uploaded_file($f_tmp, $store)){
             $product_details[$i] = $f_newfile;
          }
        }
     } else {
       echo 'file type invalid';
     }
  }
```

Note: Do not forget to use multiple attribute while uploading multiple files
at once. Also remove read-only attribute as it'll make input read-only hence meaningless.

Comment: counting `$_FILES['myfile']` will not give you the correct result

Comment: You should be using `===` rather than `==` comparison. It's not too vital for strings but it's a bad habit to get into.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through this step by step:

## 1:

> I added [] because I have multiple row that requires more image to be uploaded for each row.

Ok, to upload multiple files in one call, you need to add the `multiple` keyword to your input element. Also making your element `readonly` seems somewhat at odds with uploading files.....

```
<td><input type="file" class="form-control total" name="myfile[]" multiple></td>
```

## 2:

The error you report states:

> Warning: end() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in ... on line 39

Which is pretty clear; you're passing it a string when it expects an array. This is obvious from the typo on line 38:

```
$f_extension = implode('.',$f_name);
```

Your line here is taking an *array* of values (`$f_name`) and compacting them into a *string*

As you can see from the error, the `end` function expects an array, not a string.

The solution to this is to stop imploding. As [commented by Nigel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64183577/end-expects-parameter-1-to-be-array-string-given-when-working-with-files#comment113498065_64183577) you almost certainly are looking for [*explode*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/explode) not [*implode*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/implode).

[`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) breaks a string into an array of parts. [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) does the *exact opposite*.

## 3:

You further reference in your comment:

> when i use explode, it returns this Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

This is the crux of your issue and is because you are defining a *multiple file upload* rather than a single file.

As outlined [in more detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php), when uploading files via PHP there are two structure layouts, one for single files and one for multiple sets of files.

You are coding as if you're using single files, but the data being given to PHP from the upload process is actually for multiple files, here is an example of the difference:

## Single file:

```
  $_FILES['myfile']['name'] = 'filename';
  $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'] = '/some/temp/server/addres';
  $_FILES['myfile']['size'] = 345;
  $_FILES['myfile']['error'] = 0;
  $_FILES['myfile']['type'] = 'file/mimetype';
```

## multiple files:

Uploads marked as `Multiple` always have the same structure regardless of if they're uploading 1 or 10 files. The elements will **always** be numeric arrays rather than strings.

```
  // Each of these values are now numerical arrays, one for each file.
  $_FILES['myfile']['name'][0] = 'filename_1';
  $_FILES['myfile']['name'][1] = 'filename_2.css';
  $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][0] = '/some/temp/server/address_1';
  $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][1] = '/some/temp/server/address_2';
  $_FILES['myfile']['size'][0] = 345;
  $_FILES['myfile']['size'][1] = 678;
  $_FILES['myfile']['error'][0] = 0;
  $_FILES['myfile']['error'][1] = 0;
  $_FILES['myfile']['type'][0] = 'file/mimetype';
  $_FILES['myfile']['type'][1] = 'text/css';
```

So you should be able to see the difference, you are treating the `$f_name` as if it is a *string* when it is actually an *array* of all name values of all uploaded files.

```
  $f_name = [
            $_FILES['myfile']['name'][0],
            $_FILES['myfile']['name'][1],
            $_FILES['myfile']['name'][2]
            ];
```

Therefore, `$f_extension` returns an error when you `explode` it into an array because its subject is *already an array*.

Here is some [further information about Multiple File Uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php), as well as the [PHP Manual documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php).

## 4: How to fix this

I could show you how to fix this issue, but really, you should **NEVER EVER TRUST USER DATA**, so you must never trust the file extension set in the `name` key, or the mime type.

Instead you should [read this Stack Overflow question](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php) and have your server independently check the mime type of the file that's been uploaded and then set an appropriate extenstion string.

Typically you should use [FileInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) to check the expected file type and use a `switch` statement to then find the correct extension, such as (*rough example*):

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type extension

// For a single file
$mimeType = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);

// OR

// For a multiple file in a loop ($i)
$mimeType = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$i]);

// The above will return some form of mime type, check this format to set the extension:

$extension = "";
switch($mimeType){
   case "image/jpeg":
       $extension = ".jpeg";
       break;
   case "image/gif":
       $extension = ".gif";
       break;
   case "image/png":
       $extension = ".png";
       break;
   default:
       $error = "BAD! Invalid file MIME Type";
       // do something here. Feed error back to user.
}

finfo_close($finfo);
```

**P.s** [Useful list of common mime types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types)