# Add multiple images with php and save it in mysql

Tags: javascript, php, web

Someone can help me please with this code? I would add multiple images but I can't figure it out.
I tried the multiple command but it doesn't worked, I have no clue honestly.

HTML code:

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-abide>
<div class="photo-field">
<input type="file" name="file_img" pattern="^.+?\.(jpg|JPG|png|PNG|jpeg|JPEG)$" required>
<small class="error">Upload JPG or PNG only.</small>
</div>
<div class="title-field">
<input type="text" name="img_title" placeholder="Image title" required>
<small class="error">Image title is required.</small>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="btn_upload" class="button">
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
 <li><a href="upload-photo.php" data-reveal-id="uploadModal" data-reveal-ajax="true">Add Photo</a></li>
           <li class="divider"></li>
           
        </ul>
     </section>
  </nav>
  <br/>
  <!--Content goes here-->
  <div class="row">
     <div class="large-12 columns">
        <?php
        if(isset($_GET['success'])) {
        if($_GET['success']=="yes"){?>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="small-6 large-6 columns">
              <div data-alert class="alert-box success radius ">
                 Image "<?= $_GET['title']; ?>" uploaded successfully.
                 <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <?php } else {?>
         <div class="row">
           <div class="small-6 large-6 columns">
              <div data-alert class="alert-box alert radius ">
                 There was a problem uploading the image.
                 <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <?php } }?>
```

Comment: where is your upload script? which handles `$_FILES['file_img']`?

Comment: @Sysix
Sorry missed that part, u can check it here: https://pastebin.com/raw/JnjU0y4J

Comment: Do i understand it correct?  One file is uploaded correctly but multiple files are not? the pastebin code looks like only one file is processed.   or is it not working at all?? so NO file is uploaded?

Comment: Only one file is uploading, I can't upload multiple, idk why. :/

Comment: It is because there is no loop inside the pastebin upload code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that there is no loop in the processing php script.

So only one file gets uploaded.

For more info and solutions see:
[Multiple file upload in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php)

Comment: `foreach($_FILES as $file {
  {
    $filetmp   = $_FILES["file_img"]$file["tmp_name"];
    $filename  = $_FILES["file_img"]["name"];
    $filetype  = $_FILES["file_img"]["type"];
    $filepath  = "img/" . $filename;
    $filetitle = $_POST['img_title'];
    
    move_uploaded_file($file[$filetmp], $file[$filepath]);
}
`
I tried this but unfortunately not working. :/

Comment: PLEASE be more specific. 
"NOT WORKING"  is no valuable info anyone can work with. 
Please also include the new code in your original post as it is very difficult to read here. 
Try to echo some important info during tvarious steps during he processing of the file to see where the problem is occuring.

Comment: You will also have to include the db updates into the loop BUT NOT THE PREPARE  whicj should be done before.   

$stmt->bindValue(':iname', $filename);
    $stmt->bindValue('itype', $filetype);
    $stmt->bindValue('ipath', $filepath);
    $stmt->bindValue('ititle', $filetitle);
    if ($stmt->execute())  ....

Comment: The new pastebin code will not work  as you use $_FILES instead of  $file- please try to understand 
https://www.php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704314/multiple-file-upload-in-php